# Pandas: DataFrame named 'T' displayed by PyCharm as a DataFrame member, and does it preclude using 'T' as a column name?

Tags: pandas, pycharm

I am creating a new DataFrame into which I will next add a column of data named 'T'. However when stepping through my code in PyCharm I notice that the DataFrame is initialized with another DataFrame named 'T' as a member of the new instance. My assumption is that this is used as a transpose, in case it's needed when calling `df.T`. However, I have data that I want to load into the DataFrame and name its column 'T' (that's the original name, it's temperature). Is 'T' a reserved name that can't be used as a column name? I get no error when I step over the statement

`df['T'] = temperature_series`

However, the DataFrame doesn't appear to be updated with that temperature data as a new column named 'T' when looking at it in the PyCharm debugger, it instead appears to go into the ether and the transposed DataFrame 'T' remains. What's interesting however is that I can print the DataFrame after adding the temperature data and the columns prints as expected, so maybe the column is present, but due to some sort of namespace conflict it doesn't appear in the df object within PyCharm's debugger?

My assumption at this point is that this may be a bug (feature?) with how PyCharm displays DataFrame members in its debugger, i.e. it won't recognize/display a column named 'T' if it exists. Can anyone confirm, and/or explain this behavior?

Comment: Do you use `View as DataFrame` in a debugger?

Comment: No, I was looking at the values shown in the debugger window. I will try that view option, thanks for your suggestion.